# User Event Tracking using Logging module in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I developed UI(User interface) application in python (It has  5  window-frames  and  each  window with 2 buttons).  this application can be accessed by n-number of users at same time(Its multiuser business application).

Now  I am trying to develop Customized logger program which can track the user access event such as Example:when user clicked on login button I need to track "user_name","fun_name_raised',"module_name_fun_present","time_stamp","debug_level_raised","file_path" to achieve this I am going to place `logger_customized_info()` , `logger_customized_debug()` etc. in  my application wherever I need to track the above parameters (`ser_name`,`fun_name_raised`, `module_name_fun_present`, `time_stamp`, `debug_level_raised`).
I don’t want to user stream handler or File handler of logging package which give  whole buffered stream which prints all previous logs(I like to print only  calling log),
Please advice me how to achieve this.

```
application.py
---------------
def main():
    obj=Util_logger()
    obj.logger_customized_info(user_name=******,fun_name_raised,module_name_fun_present,time_stamp,debug_level=”INFO”)#custmozied logger calling
    window_frame()#calling windows frames

custom_logger.py
-----------------
class  Util_logger:
       def logger_customized_info(u ser_name=**,fun_name_raised,module_name_fun_present,time_stamp,debug_level=”INFO”):
```

Thanks
Mukthyar

Comment: The `python` tag is all you need, unless your problem is confined specifically to python 2.7 *or* python 3 *or* ironpython. Removed the excess tags.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple scripts try to write to the same file at the same time, you'll probably end up with file locking issues or race conditions. Instead of logging, I would recommend "logging" to a database like postgres or perhaps firebird or even MySQL / MariaDB. A good database can handle lots of connections at once without issue.